# SELECT record in between 2 Integers where upper bound is conditional

Tags: sql, sql-server, relational-database

I have a Table where Time Period is stored in `yyyyww` [where `ww` is a week number] format in 2 separate columns as shown below and `endweek` can be `null`.

```
startweek   | endweek   |
201501      | 201602    |
201510      | 201702    |
201803      | NULL      |
201933      | 202209    |
```

Where `NULL` in `endweek` means the time Period is endless.

Question:

Through SQL I want to get a record/records by passing a week number (`yyyyww`) which falls in any time period.

For Example:
If I pass `202001` It should return:

```
201803      | NULL      |
201933      | 202209    |
```

How can I achieve this.

Note: Database is `SQL Server 2016`

Comment: Storing dates like this is a very bad idea. But what have you tried? Probably as simple as endweek > 202209 OR endweek IS NULL

Answer (score 2):

This should work

```
declare @d int = 202001;
select * 
From table 
where startweek <= @d  
  and (@d <= endweek or endweek is null)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select * From table where 202001 Between Cast(startweek as Integer) and 
cast(isnull(endweek,'999999') as Integer)
```

Will return all records where 202001 falls within the startweek and endweek intervals. The Integer cast is necessary, so SQL does not perform string comparison instead (Slower and may lead to erroneous comparison).

Comment: Title states integers.  Direct it should use an integer comparison.   Even if it was string I would cast to integer.

Comment: isnull(endweek,999999)  would yield an int.